# PHP pagination isn't working and I'm not sure why

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I feel like I ask a lot of questions.

Anyways, I'm writing pagination for some database entries, and it looks sound to me but it's only displaying the first 10 posts and nothing else when I click the links.

The whole shebang is right here:

```
     <?php
            $post_limit = 10;

            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("failed to connect: " . $conn->connect_error); 
            }

            $sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM $tablename";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (!$result) {
                echo "you fucked up";
            } else {
                echo $row["id"];
            }

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
            $post_count = $row[0];

            if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
                $page = $_GET['page'] + 1;
                $offset = $post_limit * $page;
            } else {
                $page = 0;
                $offset = 0;
            }

            $post_left = $post_count - ($page * $post_limit);

            $sql = "SELECT id, upvotes, downvotes, name, title, message, date, time FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT $offset, $post_limit";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<br><div id='messageBar'>";
                    echo "  &#10070; </b>";
                    echo "Posted by <b>";
                    echo htmlspecialchars($row["name"]);
                    echo "</b> on ";
                    echo $row["date"];
                    echo " at ";
                    echo $row["time"];
                    if (!empty($row['title'])) {
                        echo " - <b>";
                        echo htmlspecialchars($row["title"]);
                        echo "</b>";
                    }
                    echo "<span style='float: right'>#";
                    echo $row["id"];
                    echo "</span>";
                    echo "</div><div id='messageContent'>";
                    echo htmlspecialchars($row["message"]);
                    echo "<br><br><span id='commentLink'><a class='commentLink' href='thread.php?id=$row[id]'>view thread&nbsp;</a></span>";
                    echo "<br></div><br><hr>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<center><i>it's dusty in here</i></center>";
                echo "<br>";
            }

            if ($page > 0) {
                $last = $page - 2;
                echo "<a href='$_PHP_SELF?page = $last'>previous page</a> | ";
                echo "<a href='$_PHP_SELF?page = $page'>next page</a>";
            } else if ($page == 0) {
                echo "<a href='$_PHP_SELF?page = $page'>next page</a>";
            } else if ($post_left < $post_limit) {
                $last = $page - 2;
                echo "<a href='$_PHP_SELF?page = $last'>previous page</a>";
            }

            $conn->close();
        ?>
```

The link for the next page appears at the bottom, but clicking it takes you to the page you're already on with the same 10 most recent posts.

I am trying to learn PHP as I go, so I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: The correct syntax is `$_GET['page']`, not `$_GET{'page'}`.

Comment: Thank you, fixed that syntax, but the problem remains.

Comment: It's my constant reminder that I'm terrible at programming

Comment: Please keep the swearing to an absolute minimum, including in code pieces.

Comment: change your offset `$offset = $post_limit * $page - $post_limit`; And also change your `$page` else statement. Like `if(isset($_GET['page'])){$page=(int)$_GET['page']; }else {$page=1;}`

Comment: @ToniReese Reese that didn't quite work. Nothing seems to have changed, except that when I change $page to 1 like you said, it includes the most recent posts starting with the second most recent.

Comment: I did a little messing around and I'm pretty sure it's this part that's not working: 

`if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
     $page = $_GET['page'] + 1;
     $offset = $post_limit * $page;
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alert');</script>";
    } else {
     $page = 0;
     $offset = 0;
    }`

I put an alert in it and it doesn't go off, so it's not succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$_GET` please use `$_SESSION` to manage a counter.
Every time you go in this page you increment the counter.

So, you have to do this on the top of the page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
            $page = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
            $offset = $post_limit * $page;
        } else {
            $page = 0;
            $offset = 0;
            $_SESSION['counter']=0;
        }
```

Try this.
By the way there is [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) which do what you're looking for.

P.S. If you don't start sessions in some other points in your code, please put `session_start();` in the first page (e.g., login.php) otherwise put on this page.

Comment: Just tried this out, nothing appears to have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Problem was here:

```
if ($page > 0) {
            $last = $page - 2;
            echo "<a href='$_PHP_SELF?page = $last'>previous page</a> | ";
            echo "<a href='$_PHP_SELF?page = $page'>next page</a>";
        } else if ($page == 0) {
            echo "<a href='$_PHP_SELF?page = $page'>next page</a>";
        } else if ($post_left < $post_limit) {
            $last = $page - 2;
            echo "<a href='$_PHP_SELF?page = $last'>previous page</a>";
        }
```

The URL I was linking to wasn't supposed to have spaces around the = sign. It's still buggy, but it works.